# Why does my .zshrc file throw this error when I source it?

Tags: zsh

I installed zsh on my mac but I get this error when I try to source it:

```
Last login: Sat Nov 20 15:54:12 on ttys004
➜  ~ source zsh
[2] 55808
/usr/local/bin/zsh:1: parse error near `)'
/usr/local/bin/zsh:1: bad pattern: ^@^@^@^@^@^Y^@^@^@H^@^@^@__PAGEZERO^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^Y^@^@^@(^B^@^@__TEXT^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@@^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^H^@^@^@^@^@^E^@^@^@^E^@^@^@^F^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__text^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@__TEXT^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@\M-<O^@^@^A^@^@^@\M-q
/usr/local/bin/zsh:1: parse error in command substitution
[2]  + 55808 exit 1     ����X�
```

I copied the  `zshrc.zsh-template` from templates as my .zshrc file so I don't even know if the problem is with zsh. It just happens when I run `source zsh`. I can't figure out what causes this or how to fix it.

Comment: You're trying to source the zsh executable, not a zsh dialect shell script.

Comment: @DanGoodrick : `zsh` is a binary! What do you expect from sourcing a binary????

Comment: Note that the argument to `source`, if it doesn't contain a `/`, is subject to path lookup, which is why `zsh` resolves to `/usr/local/bin/zsh`, rather than just giving an error that no file named `zsh` was found.

Answer (score 1):

The proper source command is `source ~/.zshrc`